# to print a 2-d array (m * n) in python

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

```
import numpy as np

a = (['a','b','c',],['d','e','f','g'],['h','i','j','k'])

for row in a:
    print row

for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(0,4):
        print a[i][j]
```

I want to print an array where `n!=m`. My code above I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pankajsehgal/mystuff/Python_Practise/2darray", line 10, in <module>
    print a[i][j]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know it is out of range, is there any way to print it. without using numpy.

Comment: and i cannot use this also,  
print(np.matrix(A))

Comment: i am not missing, array is like that only

Comment: What's wrong with `for row in a: for item in row: print item`? I also fail to see the connection to `numpy`.

Comment: thats the simple solution i was trying for.

Comment: also i dont want to use `numpy`

Comment: If you are in desperate need of the index, use `enumerate()`. Example: `for i, row in enumerate(a):`

Comment: Do you mind, if I ask, why a Python beginner learns to code in Python 2 instead of Python 3? Afaik, it is not worth the effort. Python 2 will be less common in the future and Python 3 behaves differently in many areas.

Comment: i took your advice, will continue to learn in python3

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a = (['a','b','c',],['d','e','f','g'],['h','i','j','k'])

for row in a:
    print row

for i in range(len(a)):
    sublistlen = len(a[i])
    for j in range(0,sublistlen):
        print a[i][j]
```

Or just:

```
import numpy as np

a = (['a','b','c',],['d','e','f','g'],['h','i','j','k'])

for row in a:
    print row

for lis in a:
    for item in lis:
        print item
```

Comment: @Pankaj If you're just looking to print the items in the lists, the second option in this answer is the way to go.  It's the cleanest and easiest to understand for anyone looking at your code!